# ¿Cómo añadir una funcion onclick al construir elemento con javascript?

Tags: javascript

Intento crear y mostrar un elemento no mediante de html sino por javascript.
mi idea es añadirle una funcion

```
    var loadFile;
    loadFile = document.createElement('input');
    loadFile.id = 'carga';
    loadFile.type = 'file';
    loadFile.name = "archivo";
```

para que quede como si lo escribiera por html añadiendo "`onclick="myFunction()`"

```
<input id="carga" type="file" name="archivo" style="color: transparent; width: 120px;" onclick="myFunction()">
```

como podría hacerlo?

Comment: por que en un input de tipo file? si ese es pensado para subir un archivo? por favor se mas claro en tu pregunta

Comment: Ya la edite @element.
es posible?

Comment: Juan @element tiene razón, no tiene sentido añadirle un `onclik` a un input del tipo `file`. El evento que se lanza al hacer click sobre él será la apertura del seleccionador de archivos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar [**`addEventListener`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) para asignar una función al elemento de forma programática. Claro está, esa función debe existir en el contexto para que no te dé error.

Sería esto simplemente:

```
loadFile.addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);
```

O sea, la asignas el *listener*  onclick del elemento a la función `myFunction`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
var mDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
var loadFile;
loadFile = document.createElement('input');
loadFile.id = 'carga';
loadFile.type = 'file';
loadFile.name = "archivo";
loadFile.setAttribute('style', 'color: transparent; width: 120px;');
loadFile.addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);

mDiv.appendChild(loadFile);

function myFunction() {
  console.log("Se presionó: " + this.id);
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: buenisimo, solo me hace falta hacer que cuando se cargue la pagina se abra ese boton .

Comment: @JuanOrtiz *¿que cuando se cargue la pagina se abra ese boton?*  Me temo que tendrías que explicar en otra pregunta de qué se trata, una vez lo hayas intentado y no hayas podido, claro está :). Me alegro de que te haya servido. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Te paso un ejemplo donde creas un elemento HTML de tipo input y lo añades dentro de un elemento DIV:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {

        // Div principal
        var div = document.getElementById('div_principal');

        // Crear un nuevo elemento input
        var nuevoInput = document.createElement("input"); 

        // Agregar atributos al elemento html
        nuevoInput.id = 'carga';
        nuevoInput.type = 'file';
        nuevoInput.name = "archivo";

        // Añadir elemento input dentro del div
        div.appendChild(nuevoInput);

    }
</script>

<div id="div_principal"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias element, sigo teniendo problemas para enviar código en las respuestas. Lo resolveré antes de volver a escribir una respuesta. Saludos